# how do I play a haptic on objective-c for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, haptic-feedback

I am  wondering how to play haptic feedback when a button is pressed in objective-c, I've tried looking into the documentation but don't know how to read it.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics?language=objc and look at the Haptic Feedback section. Now you know what classes are involved. Now search here for examples using those classes. Once you've tried something, update your question with what you have tried and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: will do thank you!

Comment: I just used the audioToolbox version.

Comment: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);